# JAVA_HOME errors when run without sudo

Tags: java, linux-mint

Hello I am on Linux Mint 16 KDE 64.

I have OpenJDK 7 installed and Oracle JDK 7 and if I run Intellij as a normal user I get:

> 'tools.jar' seems to be not in IDEA classpath.
>   Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE

Also if I run gradle build on any of our projects as a normal user I get:

> Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.

If I run

> echo $JAVA_HOME

Then I get:

> /usr/lib/jvm/default-java

I get the same thing if I run it with sudo.

As per the comments below javac -version produces:

> javac 1.7.0_51

Same result with sudo.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You installed only JRE. Try to [install](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/java#Installation) JDK:

> sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk

Comment: Wow that actually worked. I guess I just didn't have everything setup properly when I installed the oracle jdk. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try to run `javac -version` to get version of your java compiler.

You should get answer like javac 1.7.0_something.

if it's not available then you have only Java Runtime Environment (jre), not Java Development Kit (jdk) installed and you should install the `openjdk-7-jdk` as Anton suggested.

Comment: I have updated my question with the results of javac -version

Comment: Thank you. If it was run after installing openjdk-7-jdk then it makes sense, if it was before installing openjdk-7-jdk then it's weird.

Comment: Yea that output was before I ran the sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk command.

Comment: Then I don't understand it. The intellij and gradle complain about nonexisting JDK, the javac is part of JDK but not part of JRE and it still displays javac version even without JDK installed.

Comment: Yea I didn't have any idea either. I tried everything I could think of before asking.